# The screen freezes dragging windows between workspaces in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, workspaces

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop (Samsung QX310, Intel Core i5, GeForce 310M) and the problem is when I want move windows between workspaces. The system freezes!

Do you know which is the problem? Is an Ubuntu bug? Or my laptop's hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be a Unity problem as I have it on my Lenovo T430s.
It has been officially reported as a bug on Launchpad at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1301623?comments=all
Would be best if you reported that you have the problem too. Presumably the more people who report it, the more likely someone who knows what they're doing will look into it and hopefully solve the problem.

In the meantime, my son gave me a temporary fix:

1. press: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a terminal;
2. log in with your username and password;
3. type: `unity --replace` ;
4. press: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>f7</kbd> to return to the desktop.
   But the top menu bar did not return, had to shut down using a terminal - 
   type:  `sudo shutdown -h now`

Answer (score 15):

alt + enter seems to do the trick for me!

Comment: You saved me from having to reboot! :)

Comment: welcome bro!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following as a temporary fix:

- open Compiz Settings Manager
- Desktop Wall
- Viewport Switching
- Wall Sliding Duration=0

I'm not sure if it works though, this bug is somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: well seems the bug still happens sometimes.